# Is there a kde dolphin thumbnail creator for video files that would use built-in thumbnails?

Tags: kubuntu, video, kde, dolphin

There are some video thumbnailers for Dolphin: kffmpegthumbnailer, ffmpegthumbnailer, etc. However, all of them just extract random frame from the video even if there is a built-in thumbnail in video file. Nautilus, for instance, prefers built-in thumbnails and only if these are missing it extracts some frame.

Is there a similar solution for Dolphin?

Comment: The KDE applications can show a thumbnail for a file if there is a thumb creator plugin installed for the file type. More: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?67642-FAQ-KDE-preview-thumbnail . Using embedded Matroska cover art with the KDE thumbnailer: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?32568-Video-Previews&p=345474&viewfull=1#post345474

Comment: That's nice, but I mostly need this not for mkv, but for mp4 files. `totem-video-thumbnailer` does the job in nautilus, but it does not work in kde.

Comment: Using embedded mp4 cover art with the KDE thumbnailer: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?32568-Video-Previews&p=380103&viewfull=1#post380103

Comment: Well, that's great, but I can't find mp4-compatible code. Or it is supposed to be done manually? There are links to KDE-apps, but it has only version is 0.4, which I've already installed and it supports only mkv files.

Comment: There will be a release for the KF5 maybe for the KDE4. But meanwhile with the KDE4: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?25740-Service-Menus-with-Dolphin&p=380180&viewfull=1#post380180

Comment: Better late than never - adding a proper answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**KDE thumbnail creator with an option to use built-in thumbnails**

[image]

A KDE bug/wish: Bug 238909 - Enabling of embedded mkv /mka cover art to display as icon - https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=238909

Meanwhile: A KDE thumb creator plugin with an option to use the external pictures as thumbnails: http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/FFMpegThumbs-MattePaint?content=153902 . The external is at this same as attached/embedded thumbnail.

Both the MPEG-4 container and the Matroska container could have cover art as attachments.

The FFMpegThumbs-MattePaint is capable to use the embedded/attached mp4/Matroska cover art as the thumbnail. The thumbnailer is using AtomicParsley /1/ command-line tool (mp4) and Matroska /2/ command-line tools (mkv) to extract the cover art and use it as the thumbnail. Both tools are available from the Ubuntu repositories.

As default the FFMpegThumbs-MattePaint, 0.42 or later, is using the attched/embedded mp4/Matroska cover art for the thumbnail. If there is no attached picture or the picture extraction is not possible (missing tool etc) then the thumbnail creator will pick a random frame from the media.

A YouTube clip https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iRz3aWnD21Q&feature=youtu.be

The user has an option to override the default by writing an empty, 0 byte, file to the ../ffmpegthumbs-mattepaint/NoAuto.

*KDE4:*

This can be done by the command:

```
touch ~/.kde/share/apps/ffmpegthumbs-mattepaint/NoAuto
```

*KF5:*

This can be done by the command:

```
touch ~/.config/ffmpegthumbs-mattepaint/NoAuto
```

If there is more than one picture file attached the user has an option to hand pick the wanted cover.

[image]
Thumbnail picking from the Matroska cover art sample file: http://matroska.org/news/cover_art.html

**Links**

1. http://atomicparsley.sourceforge.net/
2. https://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/

Answer (score 0):

There was some activity in [kffmpegthumbnailer repository](https://github.com/dirkvdb/ffmpegthumbnailer/tree/master/kffmpegthumbnailer) and it is now supports creating thumbnails from embedded covers. So it seems to be quite good solution for this problem. I've been using it for quite some time now, and it fulfills the task perfectly.